# margin:0 auto; is not working to put one div center of another div

Tags: html, css

I am developing a web page where I am  trying to put one div exact center on of an another div , For this, I am using `margin:0 auto;` but it is not working in code . Please help me  how I can put LogoDiv exactly center of backgroundDiv.

```css
/*css file */

body
{
 margin:0;
 padding:0;
 font-family:Gotham, "Helvetica Neue", Helvetica, Arial, sans-serif; 
 position:relative;
 overflow-x:hidden;
}

*
{
 margin:0;
 padding:0;
}

.container
{
 max-width:100%;
 border:1px solid rgba(6,0,0,1.00);
 margin:auto;
}

.backgrounddiv
{
 background:url('../images/bg_page_01.png');
 background-size:100%;
 background-repeat:no-repeat;
 height:800px;
}

.LogoDiv
{   
    clear:both;
 position:absolute;
 background:url('../images/logo_fianl.png');
 background-size:100%;
 background-repeat:no-repeat;
 height:250px;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>

<html>   
<meta charset="UTF-8">
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width,initial-scale=1,maximum-scale=1,minimum-scale=1"/>
<head>
<!-- Bootstrap CSS -->  
<link rel="stylesheet" href="CSS/bootstrap.min.css">
<!-- style CSS-->
<link rel="stylesheet" href="CSS/style.css">
</head>
<body>
<div class="container">
<div class="row">
<div class="col-xs-12 .col-sm-12 .col-md-12 .col-lg-12 backgrounddiv">
<div class="col-xs-5 .col-sm-5 .col-md-5 .col-lg-5 LogoDiv">
</div>
</div>

</div> <!-- End of row -->
</div> <!-- End of Container -->
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 1):

You can try below code:

[Working demo](https://jsfiddle.net/jjehquyh/9/)

```
.LogoDiv
  {   
    clear:both;
    position:absolute;
    top:50%;
    left:50%;
    transform:translate(-50%, -50%);
    background:#fff;
    width:500px;
    height:250px;
}
```

Comment: please suggest with responsive code because after changing device width it is not rendering perfectly.

Comment: @ArpitGupta its working perfectly fine I guess, don't understand why you say its not rendering perfectly.

Answer (score 0):

You have to set a width for `.container` :

```
/*css file */

body
{
    margin:0;
    padding:0;
    font-family:Gotham, "Helvetica Neue", Helvetica, Arial, sans-serif; 
    position:relative;
    overflow-x:hidden;
}

*
{
    margin:0;
    padding:0;
}

.container
{
    width: 600px;
    max-width:100%;
    border:1px solid rgba(6,0,0,1.00);
    margin:auto;
}

.backgrounddiv
{
    background:url('../images/bg_page_01.png');
    background-size:100%;
    background-repeat:no-repeat;
    height:800px;
}

.LogoDiv
{   
    clear:both;
    position:absolute;
    background:url('../images/logo_fianl.png');
    background-size:100%;
    background-repeat:no-repeat;
    height:250px;
}
```

Demo: https://jsfiddle.net/wr9awq4s/

Comment: could you please provide me fiddle with sample working code

Comment: @ArpitGupta I add it to my answer.